# Laravel API request Response Time higher than function execution time

Tags: php, laravel, api, request, response-time

When I make an API request to local env back-end using Postman, it takes roughly 5 seconds.
When I do the same to production back-end, it goes back and forth between 5 seconds and ~20ms.

It's a simple API request to a small table (< 1000 rows)

The strange thing is, I used timestamps to check how long the function takes to run, and it tells me it takes ~100ms. Something else seems to be causing this function to run after waiting for ~4 seconds.

Any idea on what could be causing this?

```
Route::get('/sample','SampleController@find');

class SampleController extends Controller{

    public function find(Request $request)
    {
        $time_start = microtime(true);
        error_log('Start time: '.$time_start.' Seconds');

        $curr = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        $content = SampleModel::where('start_time','<=',$curr)->get();
        $res = response()->success($content);

        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
        error_log('Total Execution Time: '.$execution_time.' Seconds');
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post code, not screenshots of it. StackOverflow supports direct embedding of code. How frequently does it switch between 5s and 20ms - every request? Every few mins?

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the screenshots with the code. It takes 5 seconds two~three times, takes 20ms two~three times. It seems pretty random

Comment: My suspicion is your issue lies elsewhere in the application - some piece of middleware or application-wide code that's running, perhaps one that involves external network calls that get cached, but only for a short time.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll look into that and get back if I find the source of the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Seems to be the middlewares and services as @ceejayoz suggested. I'm not sure why it happens only every once in a while in production environment though